# Setting control to be content of several controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a control which i'm putting in dialog as a content. Due to relization of this dialog i have to create it every time when i need it(Show/Hide won't do the trick). I want my control to remember field content beetween calls. While i can apply viewmodel to achieve this i prefer just keep control as a field and assing it as content of dialog every time i need it. But i run into following error:

"Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first."

I tried to assing null to dialog window's content before closing it, but it doesn't solve the problem. Is there anything i can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting window.Content = null works fine for me. Following is the code I used:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestWindow testWindow = new TestWindow();
        testWindow.Content = textBlock;
        testWindow.Closing += HandleTestWindowClosing;
        testWindow.Show();
    }

    void HandleTestWindowClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var testWindow = sender as TestWindow;
        if(testWindow!=null)
        {
            testWindow.Content = null;
            testWindow.Closing -= HandleTestWindowClosing;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm, after putting Content setting to event hadler instead of my method everything works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following **working** example. It isn't exactly your scenario, but pretty close. The key is setting the 'Child' property to null. It moves the TextBox from the top border to the bottom.

```
<Window x:Class="SO.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Click="Move_Click">Move</Button>
        <Border x:Name="topBorder" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ctrl">Some Text Block</TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <Border x:Name="bottomBorder" Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the code behind:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace SO
{
    public partial class MainWindow :Window
    {
        public MainWindow( )
        {
            InitializeComponent( );
        }

        private void Move_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            this.topBorder.Child = null;
            this.bottomBorder.Child = this.ctrl;
        }
    }
}
```